# How can I add a transition to my sticky navbar width when it gets sticky?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm currently building a sticky navbar which is located directly within the content of a page. The content has a little padding to each side.

When I scroll out of the viewport, my jQuery function makes my navbar sticky. Since it has a width of `100%`, it's a really unlikely size changing, which gives the user the feeling that something is not well-thought-out.

To make it look better, I've tried using `transition: width .2s` without any success to the width. I think it's not that easy since the initial width is already `100%`...

The idea is to animate the width changing in both directions to make it look a bit nicer:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let nav = $('#nav');
    let navOffsetTop = nav.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= navOffsetTop) {
        nav.addClass('sticky');
      } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
}

#nav {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: width .2s ease;
}

#nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you don't want your navbar to go full width, you can use "position: sticky;" on "#nav.sticky" element other than "position: fixed;"

Comment: Thats what I'm doing in my example ;)

Answer (score 0):

In containers, use the width as a percentage and adjust the margin auto to be in the center.

Then add an animation that navigates to the left at the same time and fills the width completely.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let nav = $('#nav');
    let navOffsetTop = nav.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() >= navOffsetTop) {
        nav.addClass('sticky');
      } else {
        nav.removeClass('sticky');
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  background: green;
  width: 90%;
  height: 1500px;
  margin: auto;
}

#nav {
  height: 60px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

#nav.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-name: smooth;
}

@keyframes smooth {
  from {
    left: 5%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div id="nav"></div>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The width of the page is pre-defined. If I change it, I would destroy a lot of default functionality...

Comment: Screens have different resolutions. You should be able to adjust it. With pixels you can not create animations for all of them. Because by setting the fixed position, you practically float the element.